# Write permission to root folder with PHP and IIS (WebsitePanel)

Tags: php, iis, file-permissions, folder-permissions

I've started to use WebsitePanel, yet. When I create a website in it, it set permissions like that:

```
-> username
    -> domain.tld 
       -> wwwroot => Web Anonymous Account to Read(or write if you set)
```

With this permission setup, php scripts(like wordpress update) can't write to root folder(wwwroot). But it can write only subfolders like "wwwroot/subfolder/test.txt". But it can't write like "wwwroot/test.txt"

Actually, before website panel, I used to set permissions like that:

```
    -> domain.tld Web Anonymous Account to "List Folder Content"
       -> wwwroot => Web Anonymous Account to Read(or write if you set)
```

By this way, php can write to root folder and sub folders without problem.

Is there any php/iis settings for websitePanel's default permission setup? Or can I change websitepanel's permission template? Because there are a lot of websites to add in to websitePanel. And I don't want to give "list folder content" permission to each domain folder.

Comment: This is off topic for our site. Might be better to ask WebsitePanel directly or on their support forums (if they have any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this artical its very use ful to you

http://koderguru.com/tutorials/phptutorials/permissiondenyiis.php

This is a common problem many PHP programmers are troubled with, when developing php scripts or installing php scripts in the IIS/Windows server . This is a very common problem when you are going to install third party scripts like Wordpress, Joomla , Mambo etc. or going to write your own thumnail script or other file handling script which requires files to be modified by PHP. By default IIS on Windows give read permission on files/folders but does not give write permission to them. To avoid this problem you have to set write permission to the files/folders on IIS. I'll describe the steps that you should take to assign write permission to the files/folders in IIS.

In this tutorial I will discuss three three ways of setting wright permission to folders on IIS

**1) Setting write permission in the local IIS**

**2) Setting write permission in online server using FTP client**

**3) Setting write permission in online server using CPanel**

**IIS for Windows XP**

1) Open "My computer" by Double clicking the Icon on the desktop. Then Tools -> Folder Options(This step is not needed for windows 2000 and 2003)

[image]

Step 2) Now go to "View" tab and uncheck the "Use simple File sharing (Recomended)" Check box.(This step is not needed for windows 2000 and 2003)

[image]

Step 3) Now open the root folder of IIS "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot" and select the folder/file within root folder (say Wordpress folder) , that you want to set write permission. Right click on the folder and select "properties" ( very last item in the pop up menu).

[image]

Step 4) Now open the "Security" Tab . Here you will see the different types of users in a list and when you select any user there are checkboxes for different permissions for that user will appear. You can check/Uncheck the boxes for granting / Revoking the permission for that user. Select "Internet Guest account" and "Launch IIS Process Account " respectively and Check the read , write, execute permission.

[image]

**Setting permission through ftp client (I have used FileZile client free version here).**

Step 1) Connect filezilla to the server .Right Click on the file/folder you want to assign permission .Select "File Attributes".

[image]

Step 2) Now assign permission as shown in the picture below.

[image]

**Setting permission using Cpanel**

Step 1) Login to your Cpanel account and goto "File manager".

[image]

Step 2)Now select the file/folder you want to assign permission in the left panel .Select "Change Permissions " in the right Panel.

[image]

Step 3) Change the premission.

[image]

So this is the process how you can assign write permission to IIS folders.

Comment: why people haven't upvoted this is beyond me. great answer.

Comment: Lol 10 years later - this solved my issue!

Comment: My php script wasn't creating folders inside wwwroot because the folder had no write permissions on the IIS_IUSRS. Great answer. Thanks